# Is X+Y sorting problem still an open problem?

Tags: algorithm

I have found that `X + Y sorting` is an open computer science problem but that book was too old and then I have google it but didn't find any strong evidence that it is still open or there is an algorithm that can solve it in O(n<sup>2</sup>) comparison without using `Fast Fourier Transform`.

Is there any algorithm proposed that can solve it in O(n<sup>2</sup>) comparison or `is it still unsolved`?

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate to https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: On a quick search at google, I've found an article [Sorting the sums (xi + yj) in O(n^2) comparisons by Jean Luc Lambert] that claims to solve the problem of the comparisons (and also generalises the problem to higher dimensions). But his algorithm is inefficient because of needed transformations.